# Change 404.html Location Fedora

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, fedora, http-status-code-404

Which file do i Edit in fedora to set the 404 page

I looked at php.ini couldn't find anything in there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 404 error page depends on the web server, not PHP.

If the webserver is apache, the 404 error message or page displayed is controlled by the ErrorDocument directive.

[apache documentation related to custom error pages](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/en/custom-error.html)

Comment: Where is the apache config edit file?

Comment: P. S. I would vote you up but i require 15 reputation points :(

Comment: it is usually /etc/apache2 or /etc/httpd. I don't use Fedora so it may differ a bit

Comment: ty found it................

Comment: Note that you can also do 404 redirection from the .htaccess file, which means you can override the server default and have different 404s for different sites/directories.

Comment: ooo Nice Should post that as an answer. Might help others